# How to test fiber patch cables?

Tags: cable-management

I am in the market for some simple fiber testing equipment. I have power meters, and OTDR's, etc. What I am curious about is if anyone has any quick and simple methods for validating if a fiber patch cable is good/bad?

Example situation: Sysadmin complains that fiber connection is offline, asks us to check the connection. With Copper Ethernet you can just unplug the cable from the server/device and plug it in to any of a million Ethernet test devices and it will connect to the switch on the other end and tell if the connection is good/bad. I would love to find a tester which could do something similar for fiber. Even better if it could test 10g fiber.

I have a Fluke Linkrunner I use occasionally that can do basic link testing through an SFP. I believe it is testing more if it can receive bits than to test power/loss. Unfortunately Fluke thought to discontinue this model and I have been unable to locate a substitute.

Comment: Shine a flashlight down the fiber and see if you can see it at the other end. ;)

Comment: You are correct Fluke Linkrunner has been discontinued. They have introduced new product FI-500 FiberInspector Micro.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the "Senko Fibre Checker Visible Light-Source VFL 650nm" tester may be what you are looking for to allow quick visual verification and depending on the tests you are looking to do.

Senko also have some other testers that you may find more suitable.

Hope this helps.